# How to keep 2 history files? One with timestamp, the other without

Tags: linux, bash

The reason I want to achieve this, is because I'd like to remove duplicates for easier command retrieval on the one hand, 
while still having the option of going over everything along with the timestamp, in case something bad happens, and perhaps going over what commands I executed can help somehow.

Here is what I currently have, which doesn't work for erasing duplicates, because of the timestamp (but of course even if it employed a regexp to be able to delete duplicates with unique timestamps, I would lose the ability to see a list of all commands executed)

```
export HISTFILESIZE=100000000
export HISTSIZE=100000000
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="[%F %T] "
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:erasedups
shopt -s histappend
PROMPT_COMMAND="history -n; history -w; history -c; history -r; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
#http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18212/bash-history-ignoredups-and-erasedups-setting-conflict-with-common-history
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you copy the history file to another file, removing the timestamp?

Comment: Removing the timestamp and removing duplicates you mean? Doing it in real time will cause a pause I would assume. It is supposed to be instant like when you press ctrl + R. Or perhaps Im mis understanding what you're suggesting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could think of a simple solution for this. Use `bash` utils to print the command output without the time-stamp like below:-

```
history | awk '{ s = ""; for (i = 4; i <= NF; i++) s = s $i " "; print s }' | uniq
```

Note:- The `history` configuration `$HISTTIMEFORMAT` must be as specified in the question with the time-stamp for the `awk` command to work. It basically prints all the columns after the time-stamp and passes it to `uniq` which omits repeated lines. You could even just write ( `> logfile`) the contents to a file in `$HOME`.

You could also add the commands as a bash function and run it parallel with the original `history` command.

Add the following lines to `~/.bashrc` file

```
function history_cool() {
   history | awk '{ s = ""; for (i = 4; i <= NF; i++) s = s $i " "; print s }' | uniq 
}
```

With this you can now run your commands `history` and `history_cool` in parallel

```
  $  history
  0  [2016-04-22 17:54:58] echo "foo"
  1  [2016-04-22 17:55:06] echo "bar"
  2  [2016-04-22 17:55:30] ls
  3  [2016-04-22 17:55:39] echo "foo"

  $  history_cool
  echo "foo"
  echo "bar"
  ls
```

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer! What worries me a bit, is that running the awk and particularly the uniq, every time i want to quickly look up a command will be slow when the file is big. But I guess worrying about it is a sort of premature optimization. Ill have to just test it and see